# Permissions error when attempting to "View All" Activities in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, error, activities, activity-timeline

When I log in as one of our users from a desktop browser and click the "View All" button on the Activities (timeline) component, I get the following error message:

> You can't view this page, either because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices.

[image: 'Sorry to interrupt' error modal]

The user has "Access Activities" permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the (Classic) page layout used on the Lightning page and add the "Open Activities" and "Activity History" related lists to the page.

[image: Add Activities related lists to Classic layout]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uqzh.png)

Apparently, then--to some extent--the Activity component on the Lightning page relies on the Classic page layout to determine which activities can be exposed through it.

Comment: Even after adding these two to the page layout, i'm still facing the same issue. Any other access or permission i need to check..?